# Facebook Graph API v2.0: get upcoming events including birthdays

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I know that Facebook's v2.0 of the graph API restricted the friend permissions so you can no longer get friends' birthdays. I can make a request to /me/events/not_replied [or whatever status] and i can see upcoming events no problem. This does not contain upcoming birthdays though.
The reason i suspect birthdays may be accessible somewhere is that on my personal Facebook page, under 'Events', i can see a list of upcoming events including birthdays. 
I'm using the newest Facebook SDK (3.15.1) for iOS but also using the Graph API explorer in developer.facebook.com.
Could someone confirm whether upcoming birthdays are accessible in any way using the 2.0 graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upcoming birthdays are not events and that is why you don't see them when you are looking at upcoming events.

And you are correct. You can not access friends birthdays in API v2.0